# Parallel = "tests" not working in Grid

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-grid

Following is my Methods code :

```
package testcases;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.ResultsPage;
import utilities.ExcelReader;

public class methodDefinations extends base {

    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void setUp(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println(browser);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = null;
        System.out.println("before driver==null")
        if(browser.equals("firefox")){
            System.out.println("ff");
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY); 
        }
        else if(browser.equals("chrome")){
            System.out.println("ch");
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
        }
        System.out.println("inside driver==null");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities); 
        System.out.println(capabilities);
        String browserName = capabilities.getBrowserName();
        String browserVersion = capabilities.getVersion();
        System.out.println("Browser = " + browserName + " "+browserVersion);
        System.out.println("before testsiteurl");
        driver.get("http://keep.google.com");
        System.out.println("after testsite url");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void doLogin()
    {
        System.out.println("after maximize");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Email")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#next")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Passwd")).sendKeys("q1w2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9p0");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#signIn")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]")).sendKeys("example");
        System.out.println("example typed");
    }
}
```

Following is my Test Case :
    package testcases;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    
import utilities.ExcelReader;

public class testCasess {
    @Parameters("browser")
    @Test
    public void setup(String browser) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        methodDefinations md = new methodDefinations();
    md.setUp(browser);
}

@Test
public void login()
{
    methodDefinations md = new methodDefinations();
    md.doLogin();
    md.tearDown();
}
```

Following is my XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" >
    <test name="LoginTest">
    <parameter name = "browser" value= "firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="testcases.testCasess"/> 
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test name="LoginTest2">
    <parameter name = "browser" value= "chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.testCasess"/>
    </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test --> 
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Parallel = "tests" not working in Grid 2. 
It basically opens both the browsers. But when it comes to typing username, it types username in firefox twice. Nothing is typed in Chrome.
I dont understand why this is happening.

Following is the Base class :

```
    package testcases;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;


public class base {

    public WebDriver driver=null;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;

    public static Properties OR = new Properties();
    public static Properties Config = new Properties();
    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
    public static FileInputStream fis;



    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }



    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us what your "base" class looks like ? You can edit your question and add it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, this can only happen if your driver is static.  Basically, you should have two instances of driver to interact with them separately.

Comment: My Base class class is as follows :

Comment: I have shared my Base class.
How to create 2 instances of driver?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan

Comment: And the problem is as stated : your driver object is static.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Niharika for the kind help.
i have 1 more question regarding this.

i have edited my test cases. Have divided 1 test case into 2. but now, only first test case is running. When it comes to execute second one, it says 'null pointer exception' it is not able to find element. i think, there is some issue with driver.

Comment: In Grid, can we make multiple test cases or it all has to be done in 1 test case only?

Comment: i have checked it. When control goes to second test case (doLogin), there value of driver is null. How will driver get value here?

Comment: i'm sorry. that base class was incorrect.
i have added the updated one again. Please can you check it.

Comment: yes. actually, i pasted incorrect base class here, by mistake.

Comment: I Basically want to ask in a nutshell and in principle :
If i create 2 classes for 2 Test Cases, how will the driver be passed to second class?

Answer (score 0):

My Base class is as follows :

```
package base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;


public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties OR = new Properties();
    public static Properties Config = new Properties();
    //public static Logger log = Logger.get
    public static FileInputStream fis;



    @BeforeSuite
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    public void setUp(String browser) throws MalformedURLException{
        if(driver==null)
        {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/properties/OR.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                OR.load(fis);
                //log.debug("OR file loaded");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/properties/Config.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Config.load(fis);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("*******************");
            driver = Browser.getDriver(browser);

            driver.get(Config.getProperty("testsiteurl"));

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10L);




        }


    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("Closing browser");
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```